# Android compose navigation screen is called many times

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a stiuation where I am not sure if it is normal or a problem. I wanted to be sure if this is acceptable and asked this question. Here is the details:

I have an android application with compose and navigation. I have 1 activity and many screens. One of these screens is MerkeziSahne and the other is TalimSahnesi. When the application is opened, MerkeziSahne is displayed. With a button in MerkeziSanhe, we can navigate to TalimSahnesi.

When I click TalimSahnesi button, here is what happens:

1. MerkeziSahne is called,
2. Then TalimSahnesi is called, and drawn,
3. Again MerkeziSahne is called,
4. Then again TalimSahnesi is called, and drawn,
5. After TalimSahnesi is called, before everything is drawn,
6. TalimSahnesi is called again, and drawn.

Why is this happening? Is this related to states for compose functions? Is something causing this many redrawings?

Here is the code for NavHost:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationView(
    navController: NavHostController,
    ustIdareCubuguDataBuilder: (navController: NavHostController, sahne: Sahne) -> UstIdareCubuguData,
    merkeziSahneViewModel: MerkeziSahneViewModel,
    talimSahnesiViewModel: TalimSahnesiViewModel
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Sahne.MerkeziSahne.hedef) {

        composable(
            Sahne.MerkeziSahne.hedef,
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            }) {
            merkeziSahneViewModel.ustIdareCubuguData = ustIdareCubuguDataBuilder(navController, Sahne.MerkeziSahne)
            merkeziSahneViewModel.talimeBaslaOnClick = { navController.navigateOnce(Sahne.TalimlerSahnesi.hedef) }

            MerkeziSahne(merkeziSahneViewModel)
        }


        composable(
            Sahne.TalimlerSahnesi.hedef,
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            }) {
            val ustIdareCubuguData = ustIdareCubuguDataBuilder(navController, Sahne.TalimlerSahnesi)
            talimSahnesiViewModel.ustIdareCubuguData = ustIdareCubuguData

            TalimlerSahnesi(talimSahnesiViewModel)
        }


    }
}

private fun NavController.navigateOnce(hedef: String) {
    if (this.currentDestination?.route !== hedef) {
        this.navigate(hedef)
    }
}

private fun NavController.navigateOnce(hedef: String,
                                       builder: NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    if (this.currentDestination?.route !== hedef) {
        this.navigate(hedef, builder)
    }
}
```

I have added these navigateOnce functions. Thinking it was about these screens being called many times. However this did not change anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think i know why this is happening, I am facing the same. and came to below conclusion

1. If you are passing NavController as a param and calling it from another screen to navigate- in this case the screens are getting called multiple time
2. if any fun as a parameter if you are passing and calling it in the another screen then the screens are getting called multiple times

I have verified it in the Now in Android App from google. They also have this kinda problem and they HAVE NOT solved it yet.

This seems to be a big issue. I am trying to find a solution, if not will raise it with google

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem. Multiple activities issued because of recomposition. Maybe you have the same problem. I solved it using [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#rememberupdatedstate).

Answer (score 0):

When navigating from one screen to another using navigation in Android Compose, the destination screen is called four times because the view is being created for the screen, resulting in four invocations, similar to onCreate.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem. This is due to the enter and exit animation from your code. Even if you don't specify animation, if you look into the NavHost composable, you will see that transition from one screen to another is done via CrossFade Animation.

Any animation api will cause this behaviour and your case is one of that.

This will not pose a significant problem unless you put UI composables directly inside the content block. You can avoid problems by creating a separate composable with [stable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability) parameters